# Setting a map as background using css or using equirectangular map projection in the background

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

Consider the link http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/18/. In this link how to set a equirectangular projection like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3757119 as background or can I use an Image of map in css background, the background should be limited only to the chart above X-axis.

```
 .grid .tick {
stroke: lightgrey;
opacity: 0.7;
   }
 .grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
  }
 .chart {
  }
.main text {
font: 10px sans-serif;
 }
 .axis line, .axis path {
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
stroke: black;
fill: none;
}
circle {
fill: steelblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to obtain the background using this code

```
          body
          {
          background-image:url("image.png");
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
          }
```

And then scaling width and height of the chart